# error while checking if column value is in other columns in panda data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, types

I have a multi-thousand rowed data frame, part of which include data like the below. I also have additional columns ["FP","Y","SLC","C_ID","NR"] in this data frame.

```
z_to_s | z_to_t | s_to_t | t_p   | min  | max 
0.04   |        | 0.06   | 0.29  | 0.04 | 0.29
0.01   |        | NS     | NS    | 0.01 | 0.01
ND     |        | NS     | NS    | ND   | ND
0.04   |        | ND*    | NS    | ND*  | 0.04
       | 0.55*  |        |       | 0.55 | 0.55
19.88* |        | 0.46   | 0.09  | 0.09 |19.88
```

The "min" and "max" columns each denote minimum and maximum values from the "z_to_s", "z_to_t", "s_to_t", and "t_p" columns. ND or ND* is always considered the minimum while NS is ignored. I need to maintain the original form of the input data so my final output should look like this:

```
z_to_s | z_to_t | s_to_t | t_p   | min   | max 
0.04   |        | 0.06   | 0.29  | 0.04  | 0.29
0.01   |        | NS     | NS    | 0.01  | 0.01
ND     |        | NS     | NS    | ND    | ND
0.04   |        | ND*    | NS    | ND*   | 0.04
       | 0.55*  |        |       | 0.55* | 0.55
19.88* |        | 0.46   | 0.09  | 0.09  | 19.88*
```

To do this, I've been trying to use the below code to formulate new columns called "QC_min" and "QC_max"

```
df["QC_min"] = df.drop(["FP","Y","SLC","C_ID","NR","min","max"], axis = 1).isin(data_concat["min"]).any(axis = 1)
df["QC_max"] = df.drop(["FP","Y","SLC","C_ID","NR","min","max"], axis = 1).isin(data_concat["max"]).any(axis = 1)
```

so "QC_min" and "QC_max" has TRUE/FALSE values depending on "min"/"max" matching any one of the ["z_to_s","z_to_t","s_to_t","t_p"] column values. I want to write another line of code so if "QC_min" or "QC_max" is FALSE, I add a "*" to the end of the corresponding "min" or "max" value. However, the output from the above code shows up like this.

```
z_to_s | z_to_t | s_to_t | t_p   | min   | max   | QC_min | QC_max
0.04   |        | 0.06   | 0.29  | 0.04  | 0.29  | FALSE  | FALSE
0.01   |        | NS     | NS    | 0.01  | 0.01  | FALSE  | FALSE
ND     |        | NS     | NS    | ND    | ND    | TRUE   | TRUE
0.04   |        | ND*    | NS    | ND*   | 0.04  | TRUE   | FALSE
       | 0.55*  |        |       | 0.55  | 0.55  | FALSE  | FALSE
19.88* |        | 0.46   | 0.09  | 0.09  | 19.88 | FALSE  | FALSE
```

where all the number objects show up as false regardless of whether they match or not, while the string objects are true. I have checked my data type, wondering if this was a data type int/float/str issue. If I add an astype(str) to my "min" or "max" so my code becomes

```
df["QC_min"] = df.drop(["FP","Y","SLC","C_ID","NR","min","max"], axis = 1).isin(data_concat["min"]).astype(str).any(axis = 1)
df["QC_max"] = df.drop(["FP","Y","SLC","C_ID","NR","min","max"], axis = 1).isin(data_concat["max"]).astype(str).any(axis = 1)
```

everything becomes TRUE, regardless of the *, like this:

```
z_to_s | z_to_t | s_to_t | t_p   | min   | max   | QC_min | QC_max
0.04   |        | 0.06   | 0.29  | 0.04  | 0.29  | TRUE   | TRUE
0.01   |        | NS     | NS    | 0.01  | 0.01  | TRUE   | TRUE
ND     |        | NS     | NS    | ND    | ND    | TRUE   | TRUE
0.04   |        | ND*    | NS    | ND*   | 0.04  | TRUE   | TRUE
       | 0.55*  |        |       | 0.55  | 0.55  | TRUE   | TRUE
19.88* |        | 0.46   | 0.09  | 0.09  | 19.88 | TRUE   | TRUE
```

Where am I going wrong? Suggestions on how to fix this/do what I want to do would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If it helps, I just looked at df["z_to_s"][0] and it came out as u'0.04' while the df['min'][0] was just '0.04'. I'm now looking up why one column is Unicode and the other is not, and trying to understand how I can change this.

Comment: These column values have TRUE and FALSE. Are they strings or booleans?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ "QC_min" and "QC_max" values are Booleans based on my code.